# R: Tidymodels: Is it possible to plot the trees for a random forest model in tidy models?

Tags: r, random-forest, rpart, tidymodels

Is it possible to plot trees in random forest model ? The following is the sample dataset which can be used for explaining.
Im sorry, i didnt find any such example online and hence didnt try anything by my own.The following is just a sample workaround.

```
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins <- penguins %>%
  filter(!is.na(sex)) %>%
  select(-year, -island)
```

Splitting the data

```
set.seed(123)
penguin_split <- initial_split(penguins, strata = sex)
penguin_train <- training(penguin_split)
penguin_test <- testing(penguin_split)
```

creating the model specifications.

```
rf_spec <- rand_forest() %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  set_engine("ranger")

penguin_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_formula(sex ~ .)
```

Applying to the test data

```
penguin_final <- penguin_wf %>%
  add_model(rf_spec) %>%
  last_fit(penguin_split)
```

**Now how to plot the trees ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in function to plot a `ranger` tree or a `randomForest` tree (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548612/how-to-plot-a-randomforest-ranger-tree-in-caret) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41443/how-to-actually-plot-a-sample-tree-from-randomforestgettree)). However, the forest of decision trees is made up of 500 trees by default, it seems exaggerated to have a plot for each of them. There are some methods to plot decision trees from other algorithm such as  [`rpart`](http://www.milbo.org/rpart-plot/prp.pdf), `party` or `tree`. Have a look [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/04/a-brief-tour-of-the-trees-and-forests/) for a brief tour of these methods for plotting trees and forests .